# How to get row count from DynamoDB (iOS & PHP)?

Tags: php, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need help with querying a DynamoDB table to get the count of rows.

Consider, I have a table "Users" with three fields, "UserName", "Password" and "UserType". UserType can be "Admin", "Employee" or @"Guest". Now I want to get the count of "Admin" in the table. In SQL we write the query like this,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE UserType='Admin'
```

Now I need to do the same using DynamoDB iOS SDK. For now, I am doing it like this.

```
- (int)adminUsersCount {
    DynamoDBScanRequest *request = [[[DynamoDBScanRequest alloc] initWithTableName:@"Users"] autorelease];
    DynamoDBCondition *condition = [[[DynamoDBCondition alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSMutableArray *attrList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[[[DynamoDBAttributeValue alloc] initWithS:@"Admin"]] autorelease]];
    condition.attributeValueList = attrList;
    condition.comparisonOperator = @"EQ";
    [request setScanFilterValue:condition forKey:@"UserType"];
    DynamoDBScanResponse *response = [[AmazonClientManager ddb] scan:request];
    return response.items.count;
}
```

Here I am fetching all the rows to know that count. I know this is not the right way and is really a bad idea. I don't know how to get the count alone without fetching all the rows.

1. I want to know how to do it in iOS SDK.
2. I want to know how to do it in PHP SDK as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can not answer for PHP nor IOS SDK since I use neither of them (I use Python). But, from a low level DynamoDB point of view:

- **If all users are admin**, you can use `ItemCount` from `DescribeTable`. It is updated only every 6 hours but it's free
- **If `UserType` is the `range_key`** (excelent), you can set `Count` param of `Query` to `True` then read `Count` field of the answer.
- **In all other cases** (bad), use Scan as you would with `Query` along with your filter condition.

This said, `Query` and `Scan` will always return the the item count. The `Count` param only instruct them not to return the real items. Please note that it only spares bandwidth. It won't be any faster nor be cheaper in terms of provisioned throughput.

If you are in the 3rd case, I suggest you re-engineer your you schema as it would be *very* slow and expensive. At all requests, you will need to go through the entire table.

Comment: Thanks for drawing attention to the count parameter

Answer (score 2):

For the PHP part, you need to do a `Scan` and your code will look like...

```
$dynamodb = new AmazonDynamoDB();

$response = $dynamodb->scan(array(
'TableName' => 'Users',
'ScanFilter' => array( 'UserType' => array( 'ComparisonOperator' => "EQ", 'AttributeValueList' => array( array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING => "Admin" ) ) ) ) ));
```

Now you need to `Count` the records returned.

```
$count = (int) $response->body->Count;
```

Now print it if you want...

```
echo (string) $count;
```

For login example, you can refer to this blog entry...

[Creating Login with Amazon Web Services' (AWS) DynamoDB](http://mohit.epistlee.com/creating-login-with-amazon-web-services-aws-dynamodb)