# How to get row count of DynamoDB range keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

This is somehow related to: [How to get row count from DynamoDB (iOS & PHP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244941/how-to-get-row-count-from-dynamodb-ios-php/13253211#13253211)

However I need an efficient way to get the count for the number of range-keys for a given hash-key in an hash-and-range key table.

It should be efficient, so I hoped that something similar to `ItemCount` from `DescribeTable` (Mentioned in the answer given by @jtlebi) exists for a given range.

Example: Lets use the example provided by Amazon given [HERE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html). If I want a quick, but not totally precise count for the number of threads in a given forum. How do I achieve that without a `Scan` or a `Query`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the iOS&PHP DynamoDB SDK, but I have decent experience using the Java Low-Level API.

It depends on your meaning for precision which in-turn depends on number of writes that you are doing on a table if you want to use DescribeTableResult's ItemCount. Say the number of writes in a 6 hour window (currently it takes 6 hours to update the TableStats) is too high (several thousands) and you want to get the count using DescribeTableRequest then the count is no more close to precision. But the advantage of this is it is a free API, you won't be charged for doing this.

I would do it with Query (instead of Scan) if I need better precision. The bottom-line is it depends on how write-heavy your table is and what is the level of precision that you want.

Comment: I am using the Java Low-Level API to. I was hoping for a solution like DescribeTableResult, that was updated slowly, but could give me an effecient estimate of items some hours or even days after peak times.

How do you think an atomic counter would perform compared to a query for every request? Lets say an atomic counter is updated for every creation of a new item. Then I could request an estimate of items very quick. I don't care about that an atomic counter is not idempotent, since I only need an estimate.

Comment: That should work. Take a look at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/scala/stm.html if you are using Akka.